# Can particles have same mass and angular velocity but different radius, while being strung together?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, energy-conservation, rotation, angular-velocity

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem:

The following figure consist of 4 particles, each of mass $m$. All embedded in a rod of negligible mass. The distance between any pair of neighboring particles is $d$. The rod keeps an angle $\beta$ with respect to the $z$ axis, while it rotates with constant angular velocity $\omega$ in the given sense. The unitary vectors $\{\hat u_\rho , \hat u_\varphi, \hat u_z\}$ are perpendicular from each other and travel along with the rod. Express the answer in terms of these vectors. Q1: Find the angular momentum of the system with respect $0$

[image: System of 4 particles]

My issue here is finding the angular velocity of each mass.

Let us focus on the particle that's $3d$ away from the origin $O$. And let's call this particle Particle 1.

Since $\omega$ is constant, we can find the angular acceleration for the Particle 1 as follows:

$$
\alpha = \dfrac{d\omega}{dt} = 0
$$

And following Newtons second law for rotation we can find the torque for that particle (just the particle, not the system!)

$$
\tau = I \cdot \alpha = I \cdot 0 = 0
$$

Thus, the angular momentum is preserved. Now, let's consider a redistribution of mass: Position particle 1 right on top of the particle that's $2d$ from the origin (Let's call this particle, Particle 2). From the law of conservation of angular momentum, we have:

$$
I_1 \omega = I_2 \omega_2 \iff \omega_2 = \dfrac{I_1}{I_2} \omega
$$

Since $I = m \cdot r^2$, we know that $\frac{I_1}{I_2} \not = 1$ (each particle hass same mass but different radius),thus the angular velocities for each particle are going to be different.

Nevertheless, when i finished the exercise i got a wrong answer. I emailed my teacher wondering on what i did wrong and he sent his solution (sadly without any input on mine :( ). And i noticed that the main difference between our approaches is that he used the same angular velocity for all three masses, that is, he found the momentum for particle $i=1,2,3,4$ as:

$$
\vec l_i = m \cdot \vec r_i \times \omega \leftarrow \text{Same } \omega \text{ for each particle!}
$$

Clearly I'm in the wrong, but my intuition keeps pushing me to think that each particle should have a different angular velocity, since they travel the same angles at the same times but at different radius, the closer you are to the center, the slower is the angular velocity and thus each particle should have a different angular velocity. Could somebody explain the fault in my ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to illustrate using a top-down view of this setup as I've shown below:
[image: Angular Velocity]

If the initial position of the masses 1,2,3 and 4 are along the red dotted line then after time $t$ they are at the position shown by the blue line. You can see that the masses have moved different *distances*, like particle 2 has moved the distance $d_2$ which is smaller than particle 3 which has moved a larger distance $d_3$, and so on. However, we see that in time $t$ all the particles have moved the same *angle* relative to the origin, which is $\theta$. Thus the particles make have different speeds but they have the *same* **angular velocity** = $\omega = \theta / t$.

Comment: Thanks! you are absolutely right; my intuition was not that of **angular velocity** but rather something more akin to **linear velocity**